# Is my truth table for this Logic Circuit correct?

Tags: logic, truthtable

How would I make a truth table for this Logic Circuit

[image]

---

My attempt:

[image]

I think the logic expression would be along the lines of:

Z= −(−(A∧B)∨−(A∧B)∧−(B∧C))∧(−(A∧B)∧−(B∨C))

Comment: For example when A = 1, B = 0 and C = 1 http://i.imgur.com/TpoX7dS.png

Comment: Why are you adding examples in comments? Update the question instead.

Comment: I can't post two or more links or pictures :(

Comment: What is your question, what are you coming to us for?

Comment: Is my truth table correct? And secondly although not as important what would be the actual logic expression for this circuit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because logic diagrams are not a *programming* problem.

Comment: I could probably validate your truth table for you, but it is just a lot of hard work.  (And too much for a patently off-topic Question!) However, >>if<< your working is correct, then the real expression is `Z = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the table is correct. The logic expression can be simplified to Z=0

Comment: as for the non-simplified logic expression, that also appears to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using

[image]

Assuming I have not made an error, this reduces to False for all inputs.

```
x1 = Nand[a, b];
x2 = Or[b, c];
x3 = And[x1, And[x1, Not[x2]]];
x4 = Nor[x1, x3];
x5 = And[x3, x4];
```

The truth table:

```
TableForm[BooleanTable[{a, b, c, x5}, {a, b, c}], 
TableHeadings -> {None, {a, b, c, x5}}]
```

[image]

and `BooleanMinimize[x5]` yields `False`